# "XML style closing syntax for an empty element" issue using the jssor slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslider

Hi all i have downloaded the jssor full pack and unzipped to my website folder how come i got an error whilst copy and paste the code onto my html code that i made using adobe dreamweaver cs3.

Here are some of the errors:

> The tag: "link" has an XML style closing syntax for an empty element even though version: "HTML20" is not an XML tag language.[HTML 4.0]

sorry i'm completely not a coding savvy

Comment: Which demo that you copy the code from?

Comment: here are the code

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (40KB) instead for release -->
    <!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = (jssor.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
    <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            var _SlideshowTransitions = [
            //Fade
            { $Duration: 1200, $Opacity: 2 }
            ];

Answer (score 1):

Use `<link />` if you are writing XHTML. Use `<link>` if you are writing HTML.

You are using the former but whatever tool you are using thinks you are trying to write HTML.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Please use <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> then.

Comment: No. Use `<link>`. You're not writing XHTML.

Comment: thanks Quention i'll give it a shot and also can you take a look at my code which one i'm doing wrong? sorry i'm a beginner

Answer (score -1):

Please replace

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

with

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Thank you both JSSOR and Quentin for your assistance i'm back home from the office, i'll give that a try first thing tomorrow, and let you guys know how i went. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi guys where should i add the above code? there seems to be no link href specified in the original source the code that i'm trying to copy and paste into was from simple-fade-slideshow.source.html the slide won't start up

Comment: It's not a problem of jssor slider then. Please check your own page, find the 'link' element and add '/' before '>'.